# expcectedCycleTime in Ros2

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am migrating a ros1 melodic program to Ros2 eloquent at the moment and I was wondering if there is a function similar to "expectedCycleTime".
I use ros rate to create a loop cycle. Now i want to get dynamic access to the Rate that is set.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350222/expcectedcycletime-in-ros2/) by [pfedom](https://answers.ros.org/users/53854/pfedom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the period of the Rate object using the `period()` method which is the the inverse of the "expectedCycleTime". The API was changed to be clearer about exactly what that datatype is returning. A cycle time is not clearly a rate.

API docs: http://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1GenericRate.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pfedom](https://answers.ros.org/users/53854/pfedom/) on 2020-04-23**:
Thank you for the quick help!